# Create a nested dictionary from a dataframe where the first column would be the key for the parent dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to created a nested dictionary from a pandas DataFrame. The table is structured as below and is a lookup table that I want to create a nested dictionary from for later use.

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | 1 | happy |
| apple | 2 | sad |
| apple | 3 | not |
| pear | 1 | new |
| pear | 2 | old |
| liver | 1 | run |
| liver | 2 | fire |
| liver | 3 | old |

The format of the dictionary needs to be as below as this will allow me use it to replace the key values in another data frame with their actual meaning. Where apple, pear, liver are the columns names and the numbers are the codes used instead of the actual values *e.g.* happy

`d = {'apple':{1: 'happy', 2:'sad', 3:'not'}, 'pear':{1: 'new', 2: 'old'}, 'liver':{1: 'run', 2:'fire', 3:'old'}}`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use Pandas [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) over the column `A`, then, iterate over the groups to create the dictionary. Using the dictionary comprehension combined with the built-in function `zip`, use columns `B` and `C` as keys and values, respectively.

```py
...
g = df.groupby('A')

d = {}
for n,dfg in g:
    d[n] = {k:v for k,v in zip(dfg['B'],dfg['C'])}

print(d)
```

Output from *d*

```
{'apple': {1: 'happy', 2: 'sad', 3: 'not'}, 'liver': {1: 'run', 2: 'fire', 3: 'old'}, 'pear': {1: 'new', 2: 'old'}}
```

Comment: small suggestion: you dont need the read_csv

Comment: Thanks. This works perfectly.